# copy and paste cells in ppt textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I was wondering if someone could help me writing a code that, in a specific range (e.g A2-A5), it copies and pastes the first cell A2 in a textbox on ppt, then it goes to A3 and it copies and pastes it into another txtbox in ppt and so on until the last row.

I have this code written but this copies the whole range A2-A5 in one textbox only on ppt:
Sub OpenPoints()

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim sh1 As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim r As Range
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long


'Open Powerpoint

Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pres = PPT.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Edenred_ProjectStatus_Saxo.pptx")

'Insert open points description
Set sl = pres.Slides(1)
Set sh1 = sl.Shapes("Rectangle 40")



'Filtra per "Y"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Action&Open_Point").Range("H1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Y"

'Individuazione ultima riga
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Action&Open_Point").Range("D" & 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Action&Open_Point").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Copia colonna descrizione
Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Action&Open_Point").Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Action&Open_Point").UsedRange.Font.Underline = False
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


sh1.TextFrame2.TextRange.PasteSpecial msoClipboardFormatRTF
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: hey welcome to S.O!  the way I read it `Set sh1 = sl.Shapes("Rectangle 40")` is making a new shape and then `sh1.TextFrame2.TextRange.PasteSpecial msoClipboardFormatRTF` is copying in the text.  So I think your question breaks down into a few steps 1.  separate the data you're copying (ie `Range("A1").copy`) then create a box for it sh1 is fine.  then copy the next data (ie `Range("A2").copy`) and make a new box i.e. sh2 maybe.  try this and see it you can get that working.  Then you will be able to loop through to do as many as needed.

Comment: @user1236777 FWIW, Set sh1 = sl.Shapes("Rectangle 40") sets a reference to an existing shape; it doesn't create a new one. But as long as the shape named "Rectangle 40" exists on the slide reference by sl, the result is pretty much the same.  Francesco, try sh1.textframe2.textrange.paste instead.  That'll give you the text from Excel. You can later apply whatever formatting you need.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg its been a while since I did powerpoint manipulation, thanks!  but otherwise Francesco then the different steps are relevant, though you will need different existing shapes on the slide